# How to handle view access with reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, web-applications

If you have a web application with a (react) frontend communicating with a REST API, what is the best way to limit access to the views?

Let's say youre not creating a single page app, you have multiple server side routes all delivering a react frontend. These routes should all be protected via authentication, so basically even the (non sensitive) react frontend shouldnt be delivered to the client. Do you handle this on the frontend on every page? Or does that mean that i might be using the wrong tool? If you do a server side session login you would have to handle the authentication and thus especially the entity layer in two spots (limiting access to views and API). I guess you can propagate the web server login to the API or vice versa, but i'm really unsure of what is the best way to go here.

I really hope the question is not going to be viewed as "subjective".

Comment: I think If you're doing that much **authentication logic on the backend**, which serves the front end only to authenticated users - Then the **frontend has less to worry about authentication**.

Comment: @DJYadav So does that mean you would handle authentication in two places (web server session login to serve frontend and api login for the frontend to fetch data from)?

Comment: Authentication will be handled on the backend only. Front end will store authentication token in browser that it received during login from the backend. Then it will send that token back to backend on each request.

Comment: Also, in case of simole websites only, it is handled automatically by the backend server.

Comment: @DJYadav i understand how authentication with a REST API works, my question is how to handle not only authenticating against the API but also the web app server (serving the frontend). I don't want to have to keep the entity layer (e.g. User entity etc.) in two places for authentication. Because i also want to secure access to the frontend (files) itself.

Comment: Yes, Likewise as you said you are not aiming for a Single Paged Application : The backend will server the views(html pages) after authentication on the backend itself. BTW, which backend server you are using ?

Comment: @DJYadav Are you talking about the language/platform or the actual application server? It will most likely end up PHP for the web app server and java for the REST API(s).